# Finding a distribution that agrees with $|t|^{-1}$ away from the origin

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory

The following is from Folland's *Quantum Field Theory*:

> Let $\phi$ be a smooth compactly supported function on $\mathbb{R}$. If $\phi(0) \neq 0$, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t|^{-1} \phi(t)dt$ is unambiguously divergent. The problem is to find ways of extracting a well-defined "finite part" from it - more precisely, to find distributions $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that agree with the function $f(t) = |t|^{-1}$ away from the origin. We observe at the outset that if $F$ is one such distribution, then so is $F + G$ where $G$ is any distribution supported at the origin, that is, any linear combination of the delta-function and its derivatives. We can remove most of this ambiguity by stating the defining condition for $F$ in the following stronger form: we require that $tF(t) = \text{sgn } t$ as distributions; that is if $\phi(t) = t\varphi(t)$, then $\langle F, \phi \rangle = \int (\text{sgn } t) \varphi(t) dt$. Since $t\delta^{(n)}(t) = -n\delta^{(n-1)}(t)$, this reduces the family of allowable $G$'s to the scalar multiples of $\delta$ itself.

Despite reading the above passage multiple times, I understand very little of what its saying or the conclusions it draws. If $F$ is a distribution that agrees with $f(t)$ away from the origin, why is $F + G$ also such a distribution if $G$ is supported at the origin? Does he mean that $G$ is *only* supported at the origin, or that its support includes the origin? Where did the delta functions come into all of this? Also, we are defining $F$ to be a distribution, so why are we defining $tF(t) = \text{sgn } t$? Should this instead be a new function/distribution?

Comment: Support of $G$ is just $\{0\}$.

Comment: the equation $tF = \mathrm{sgn}(t)$ doesn't necessarily mean that $F$ is a function, it has no solution over $\mathbb R$, but it has a distributionnal solution and that is exactly any distribution that agrees with $f$ away from the origin. It is a similiar idea than the one of the principal value of $1/t$, say $G$, that satisfies $tG = 1$ but is not a function.

Comment: @Zag So is $F$ to be interpreted as a distribution that only acts on test functions that can be written as a product of $t$ and some other test function?

Comment: $F$ is only fully determined on those test functions, and that is why there is some degree of liberty when defining $F$ over all tests functions, namely the additional term $G$.

Comment: @Zag Thank you, I think I understand now.